# galera - seqno in grastate.dat equal to -1

Tags: mariadb, galera

We have Galera with 3 nodes.

Every time I restart the mariadb, it don't come okay and take long time until I manage to make it work again.

When I check the file /var/lib/mysql/grastate.dat, usually (almost always) have -1 in the seqno line

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    e373e8c7-4c87-154c-ac36-14ebe298b6d1
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

Is it okay? Is there something else that I can check Galera?

Thanks.

Comment: The crash recovery procedure in the [docs](https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/crash-recovery.html) is the best reference I've found. The `grastate.dat` file will contain a `seqno` of -1 when it is running (so that a crash doesn't leave a valid number there). Its only on a clean shutdown that it is populated afaik.

Comment: It does not crash. it happens almost every time I need to restart the Galera. it doesn't come up okay

Comment: As danblack has already explained, the `seqno` is not the problem here. When you restart Galera, are you restarting all the nodes, or just one of them? 

Can you share the mysql error logs?